# Laravel export with excel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to export some data in excel format using laravel. But in this format I want to show some other rows which i have no idea.

```
<?php
namespace App\Exports;
use App\SalesLog;
use App\SalesLogItem;
use RegistersEventListeners;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;

use App\Helpers\DateHelper;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;


class SalesExport implements FromQuery, WithHeadings,ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    use Exportable;


    public function __construct( $id,  $aircraft_name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->aircraft_name=$aircraft_name;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            '#No',
            'Item Description',
            'Unit Type',
            'Item Price',


        ];
    }




    public function query()
    {
        return SalesLog::query()->join('sales_log_items','sales_logs.id','sales_log_items.sales_log_id')
            ->where('sales_log_items.sales_log_id', $this->id)
            ->select('sales_log_items.product_id','sales_log_items.name','sales_log_items.unit_type','sales_log_items.price');
    }
 }



public function index($log_id)
{
    $flight_nr=SalesLog::find($log_id)->flight_number_one;
    $date=date('y-m-d');
    $excel_title='sales_log'.$date;

    $data=SalesLog::find($log_id);

    return (new SalesExport($log_id,$data->aircraft_name))->download($excel_title.'.xlsx');
}
```

In this code a excel document is downloaded but it shows me only this data that i take in the method query.

I want  to show some header in the beginning then a footer in the end which might have the total. Can someone help me to find which function to use ?
I am using maatwebsite 3.1

Answer (score 1):

Maatwebsite plugin does not work correctly in some circumstance and then I advice use "PHPSpreadSheet"
you can do it by
1- create excel file as template
2- read excel file
3- add your data to excel file
4- save and download it

```
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load('./reports/template.xlsx');
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getSheet(0);
$worksheet->getCell('C6')->setValue($sum_variable);
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
$file_name='result_excel';
$writer->save($file_name);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
$writer->save("php://output");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Maatwebsite\Excel` package you're using allows exporting from a blade view file. So you could design the view as you like, make a header, a footer, put an html `<table>` inside it, and use it for export. 
[Docs here.](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.0/exports/from-view.html)

Answer (score 0):

This post might help. [Click here](https://laravelcode.com/post/how-to-set-header-in-maatwebsite-excel-export-in-laravel)